# How to pass a search term back into an ajax-generated div?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Entering text to a textbox is firing an ajaxRequest to look up the Db for results. Those results should be outputted in a list, beneath the textbox and when one of the possible matches is clicked upon, its value is moved into the textbox for submission via the submit button.

The submit button then fires to another ajaxRequest/output so that the data for the selected 'John' will show in the same ajax div. (The same ajax div as the textbox form was in). That part is a separate issue that I shall work on but for now, I need to get the possible matches to display beneath the textbox into which the search characters were entered.

When positioned in the php output of a script, the process works perfectly.

I now need it to work in an ajax-generated div so I am using a listener.
However, passing data back and forth is confusing me.

So; from the beginning....I click a form submit button (visually this is a function button in a webpage - 'Lookup by name').

That successfully generates the textbox and submit button for looking up customer names eg 'John' and it is displayed in a div with the id 'ajaxDiv'. (an ajax div within the page output where all ajax-generated output will display).

As I enter 'joh' the event listener (keyup) records the keys pressed (eg 'Joh') and this outputs correctly to JS console.log();

However, I don't seem to be able to get the list of six people whose name begins with 'Joh' to display beneath the textbox. Nothing shows beneath the textbox and I expect it is because I haven't passed the search_param back to that ajaxDiv.

If this code is within the normal php flow the scripting works so I need to understand the ajax part. ( that part which should provide the listing output beneath the textbox).

Below is the code as it works in the normal php output.  It is also the code that appears in the ajax-generated div in my page.

```
<form style='float:left;padding:0' action="url-of-a-page" method='get'>
<input type='hidden' name='action' value="part_number_search" />
<table style="padding:0;position:absolute;z-index:2000;background:#eee;overflow:visible">
<tr>
    <td>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function lookup4(inputString,id,where)
{

    if(inputString.length < 2) // if the input box has less than 4 characters do not show
    {
    // Hide the suggestion box.
    $('#suggestions'+id).hide();
    } else {
    $.get("https://myURL/ajax/retailers_search_catalogue_query.php?x=62595&order_id=", {box: ""+where+"", input: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
    if(data.length >0) {
            theheight = document.getElementById(where).offsetHeight + 2 + 'px';
            leftval = document.getElementById(where).offsetLeft + 'px';
            $('#suggestions'+id).css({'top' : theheight, 'left' : leftval});
            $('#suggestions'+id).show();
            $('#autoSuggestionsList'+id).html(data);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#suggestions'+id).hide();    
        }
        });
    }
} // lookup

function fill(thisValue,where,id) {
    $(where).val(thisValue);
    $('#suggestions'+id).hide();
}
// ]]>
</script>





<input type="text" style='width: 185px' name="search_param" id="search_param" placeholder="Enter Part No. or Name" onkeyup="lookup4(this.value,4,'search_param');" />
<div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions4" style="display: none;">
    <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList4" style="position:absolute;z-index:2000;padding: 10px 0 10px 5px;background:inherit;color:#717074;left:0;white-space:nowrap;list-style: none;"> 
    </div>
</div> 


<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function SetFocus()
{
    // safety check, make sure its a post 1999 browser
    if (!document.getElementById)
    {
    return;
    }

    var txtMyInputBoxElement = document.getElementById("search_param");

    if (txtMyInputBoxElement != null)
    {
    txtMyInputBoxElement.focus();
    }
}
SetFocus();
</script>

</td>
<td style="vertical-align:top;">
  <input type='hidden' name='business_id' value="62595" />
  <input type='submit' value='Search Retail Catalogue'/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

This is the listener in the main script that outputs the ajax div.

```
// LISTENER FOR ONKEYUP
document.getElementById("ajaxDiv").addEventListener("keyup", 
function(e) 
{
var form_id = e.target.id;
var search_term = e.target.value;
//e.preventDefault();
/ console.log( 'order_id   ', order_id);

    if ( form_id === 'search_param')
    {
console.log( 'form_id1    ' + form_id);
console.log( 'search_term   '  + search_term);
    // send the data to the function that uses the data to do something.
    window.onload = newAjaxFunction( form_id, search_term );
    }   

});
```

I need the results to be placed beneath the textbox.
Having thought some more as I wrote this, I THINK I need to pass the search_param back to the ajaxDiv in the function immediately above here.  Or perhaps it should be passed back to the ajax code that submits to the query?

How should that search_param be passed back to the ajax lookup code within the ajax div (without reloading it and losing the previously entered characters - 'j', 'o', 'h' ??

Bazz

Comment: Please, could we get a minimal reproduction of the bug? I'm certain you could strip most of it and help us see the problem better...

Comment: I wonder if I take some of my explanation out, it might be more difficult for others to understand?  So; using console.log some more, I can see that the function lookup4 is not running.  If you can help me understand why it is not running,it may take me to a happier place. I'm guessing it is to do with the code being in a 'sub-page' i.e. the Ajax-generated div?  Perhaps this causes 'this' not to be a true value?

Comment: Seems like it should be called... But without having just the needed code to reproduce, it is hard to help. I am not asking to remove explanation, I ask to remove unecessary code. Also when creating a minimal, reproducible base, you make sure that you included everything needed for the understanding.

Comment: your post is WAY too long to read through. the key word I have picked up is that your code used to work fine, but does not work on dynamically generated ajaxDiv. If that is your problem. Then the problem is with your [LISTENER FOR ONKEYUP] code. When you dynamically create a div, Eg var $d = $("<div>"), apply the keyup handler on $d.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. It seems we have narrowed this down to the listener or the next js code I use to do something wit that 'heard' data?  Those are the last two blocks of code in my OP.  The listener is working though onkeyup does nothing so I have used 'keyup'    How do I pass back the heard data to the ajaxDiv or perhaps more necessary, to the lookup function.

Comment: SUCCESS :)    I moved the call of lookup4 to my listener from the ajaxDiv output. Thank you both a for a nudge.